# Spark - How to convert text file into a multiple column schema DataFrame/Dataset

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to read a text file and convert it into dataframe.

```
val inputDf: DataFrame = spark.read.text(filePath.get.concat("/").concat(fileName.get))
.map((row) => row.toString().split(","))
.map(attributes => {
 Row(attributes(0), attributes(1), attributes(2), attributes(3), attributes(4))
}).as[Row]
```

When i do inputDf.printSchema, I am getting a single column;

```
root
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
```

How can I convert this text file into a multiple column schema Dataframe/Dataset

Answer (score 1):

Solved;

```
  val inputSchema: StructType = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("1", StringType, true),
    StructField("2", StringType, true),
    StructField("3", StringType, true),
    StructField("4", StringType, true),
    StructField("5", StringType, true)
  )
)

val encoder = RowEncoder(inputSchema)

  val inputDf: DataFrame = spark.read.text(filePath.get.concat("/").concat(fileName.get))
  .map((row) => row.toString().split(","))
  .map(attributes => {

    Row(attributes(0), attributes(1), attributes(2), attributes(3), "BUY")
  })(encoder)
```